# PDFBox print output has unprintable charaters

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to try to print out some pdf documents.  they are pdf to begin with so I'm not converting text to pdf at all.  All I want to do is take the document and print it.  The problem is that when I do I get random question marks in a box instead of certain characters.  It's not always the same ones through various prints.  Sometimes it doesn't want to print capital X's sometimes it's capital H's or W's.  It does seem always like it's capital letters.  When I open the document in Adobe everything shows and prints fine.  it's only when I print it from Java.  it seems like the document fonts are all 'PDTrueTypeFont'.  anyone have any idea what might be going on?

My code:

```
PDDocument document = null;
try {
    document = PDDocument.load(queue.getDocumentPath() + "\\" + queue.getDocumentName());
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    logger_.error("Error loading document [" + queue.getDocumentName() + "]", e);
}

try {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintService service = getPrintService(queue.getPrinterName());
    job.setPrintService(service);
    job.setJobName(queue.getDocumentName());
    document.silentPrint(job);
    queue.setPrintedFlag(true);
    queue.setCompleteTimestamp(new Date());
    queue.persist();
} catch (PrinterException e) {
    logger_.fatal("Error printing pages [" + queue.getDocumentName() + "]", e);
    success = false;
}
```